# Rich Cards declining without errors?

Tags: google-search-console, rich-cards

Our project is a web app that lets users see cinema information, movies, and showtimes.

Currently the rich cards report is showing the "Fully enhanced cards" declining.

[image]

However, our Structured Data is increasing without signs of any decline. We also checked if there are any errors anywhere in the search console including the sitemap, manual actions, and crawl errors, but there no errors.

Any idea why this is happening?